View отображает цвет с другим названием
У меня есть следующий фрагмент для отображения оранжевой звезды:
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/star_foreground"
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:src="@drawable/star"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:tint="@color/orange"/>

Проблема в том, что звезда использует другой цвет:
.
Она фиолетовая. Такой цвет у меня в colors.xml есть, с названием nutritions_calories_color:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="gray_text">#A0A0A0</color>
    <color name="light_gray">#D6D6D6</color>
    <color name="orange">#FF8B03</color>  <!-- Этот цвет должен быть -->
    <color name="grey_text">@color/gray_text</color>
    <color name="light_grey">@color/light_gray</color>
    <color name="background_color">#F2F2F2</color>
    <color name="nutritions_calories_color">#6F00C6</color> <!-- А этот отображается на самом деле -->
</resources>

Если я меняю цвет nutritions_calories_color, то звезда меняется соответствующе.
Что интересно, если я переименовываю название оранжевого цвета (тупо наводясь и Shift+F6), то цвет звезды меняется: если я меняю название на my_orange, то становится оранжевой, как и надо; если на main_orange, то она вообще становится белой, как будто цвет не найден.
Я, конечно, могу просто переименовать в "my_orange" и радоваться, но это же бред какой-то.
С чем вообще может быть связано такое поведение?
UPD: Использование android:tint вместо app:tint решает проблему,
